wrong query when updating a column
I'm trying to make the following update in oracle in order to update the DT_expiration field based on the results of the subquery for the same CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER, but i keep getting the same error that i have 'ON keyword missing'; I can't figure it out what I'm missing here;
merge into per_alt_identifier a
 using 
  (
  select 
  a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER,
  case 
    when b.UNLIMITED_EXPIRATION = 1 then to_date('99991231','yyyymmdd')
    else to_date(substr(b.DATE_OF_ISSUE_EXPIRY,1,8),'yyyymmdd')
  end as dt_expiration_new
  --a.*
  from per_alt_identifier a
  INNER JOIN PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE t 
  on a.ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE = t.ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE
  inner join ORA_PER_RESID b
  on a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER = b.PERMIT_NUMBER
  )b
on a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER = b.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER
when matched then update set a.dt_expiration = b.dt_expiration_new;

Thank you!

You need () brackets around the ON clause.

yeah this is how i also tried but i still get the same error...

@cautisanca - you did that on the merge's on clause, i.e. on (a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER = b.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER), rather than the ones for the inner joins within the using clause?

The (simplified) format for a MERGE statement is:
MERGE INTO target_table tgt
  USING source_table_or_subquery src
  ON (<join condition(s)>)
WHEN MATCHED THEN...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN...

Your MERGE statement hasn't got brackets around its ON clause, hence why you're getting that error.

Tryed to guess the sample data so this could be tested.
First three involved tables with the data:
Create Table PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER AS
        ( Select  101 "CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER", 'A' "ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE", To_Date( '2024-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) "DT_EXPIRATION" From Dual Union All
          Select  102, 'A', To_Date( '2024-05-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) From Dual Union All
          Select  103, 'B', Null                                  From Dual Union All
          Select  104, 'B', To_Date( '2024-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) From Dual Union All
          Select  105, 'C', To_Date( '2024-04-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) From Dual
        );
/*
CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE DT_EXPIRATION
--------------------- --------------------- -------------
                  101 A                     2024-04-30
                  102 A                     2024-05-31
                  103 B         
                  104 B                     2024-06-30
                  105 C                     2024-04-30    */

Create Table PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE AS
        ( Select 'A' "ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE", 'Type A' "TYPE_NAME" From Dual Union All 
          Select 'C', 'Type C' From Dual Union All 
          Select 'E', 'Type E' From Dual 
        ); 
/*
ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE TYPE_NAME
--------------------- ---------
A                     Type A
C                     Type C
E                     Type E      */

Create Table ORA_PER_RESID  AS
        ( Select  101 "PERMIT_NUMBER", 0 "UNLIMITED_EXPIRATION", '20240831' "DATE_OF_ISSUE_EXPIRY" From Dual Union All
          Select  102, 1, Null       From Dual Union All
          Select  103, 0, '20240831' From Dual Union All
          Select  104, 0, '20240930' From Dual Union All
          Select  105, 1, Null       From Dual 
        );
/*
PERMIT_NUMBER UNLIMITED_EXPIRATION DATE_OF_ISSUE_EXPIRY
------------- -------------------- --------------------
          101                    0 20240831
          102                    1                  
          103                    0 20240831
          104                    0 20240930
          105                    1                     */

... your USING query
        Select      a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER,
                    --
                    Case When b.UNLIMITED_EXPIRATION = 1 Then To_Date( '9999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    Else To_Date(SubStr( b.DATE_OF_ISSUE_EXPIRY, 1, 8), 'yyyymmdd')
                    End "DT_EXPIRATION_NEW"
                    --
        From        PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER a
        Inner Join  PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE t ON( a.ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE  = t.ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE )
        Inner Join  ORA_PER_RESID b ON( a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER = b.PERMIT_NUMBER )
/*      R e s u l t :     ( f o r    U S I N G    Q u e r y )
CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER DT_EXPIRATION_NEW
--------------------- -----------------
                  101 2024-08-31       
                  102 9999-12-31       
                  105 9999-12-31         */

... and MERGE INTO ...
MERGE INTO PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER a
USING ( Select      a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER,
                    --
                    Case When b.UNLIMITED_EXPIRATION = 1 Then To_Date( '9999-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                    Else To_Date(SubStr( b.DATE_OF_ISSUE_EXPIRY, 1, 8), 'yyyymmdd')
                    End "DT_EXPIRATION_NEW"
                    --
        From        PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER a
        Inner Join  PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE t ON( a.ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE  = t.ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE )
        Inner Join  ORA_PER_RESID b ON( a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER = b.PERMIT_NUMBER )
      ) b ON( a.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER = b.CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE  SET a.DT_EXPIRATION = b.DT_EXPIRATION_NEW   
WHERE a.DT_EXPIRATION != b.DT_EXPIRATION_NEW            
-- 3 rows merged.    
/*      R e s u l t :     ( a f t e r    u p d a t e )
CD_PER_ALT_IDENTIFIER ID_PER_ALT_IDENT_TYPE DT_EXPIRATION_NEW
--------------------- --------------------- -----------------
                  101                     A 2024-08-31          -- updated
                  102                     A 9999-12-31          -- updated
                  103                     B 
                  104                     B 2024-06-30
                  105                     C 9999-12-31          -- updated */

see the fiddle here.
As mentioned in MTO's comment and shown in Boneist's answer there were missing brackets () in ON clauses, unless there is some other error in question.
